# Symfony - How to connect to remote mysql database without install mysql-server

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database with my Symfony application. I don't want to install the mysql-server package on my server if I don't need to but when I try to connect, I get the following error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                     
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  


  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory                                                          


  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Here's what my database configuration look like. In the variables, I setup `pdo_mysql` as the driver and the other fields are working well.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database.driver%
                host:     %database.host%
                port:     %database.port%
                dbname:   %database.name%
                user:     %database.user%
                password: %database.password%
                charset:  UTF8
```

**Edit1:** If I install mysql-server, it works and the error is gone.
**Edit2:** My server is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: You don't need the mysql-server package to connect to a mysql server whether that be local or remote.  You do need however, to make sure that you can connect to it using the connection parameters.  Can you connect to the remote server using the mysql command line client?

Comment: What are the actual parameters?  Nobody can tell anything from the config variables, which are standard.  It appears that symfony is trying to connect to a unix socket, so those config variables are likely not set correctly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143148/discussion-on-question-by-coachnono-symfony-how-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-dat).

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to install client on Ubuntu like this:

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

I think 5.5 is the latest.
Go here for setting up MariaDB:
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=syringa&distro=Ubuntu

makes more sense nowadays to use MariaDB instead:

---

EDIT #2

to add remote useron the remote system:

```
CREATE USER 'fooUser'@'192.168.40.200' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
```

check the user table to see if they can connect from remote system:

```
use mysql;
SELECT Host,User,Password,ssl_type from user;
```

`ssl_type` is if you are using SSL to connect, you could leave that out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the mysql-client being installed nor MariaDB

Comment: Even if the mysql-client is installed, it doesn't work. Also, I am using Ubuntu so it should be apt-get not yum!

Comment: What is `database_host` set to then? You must have some major problems.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk Read through the comments on the question.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Also, I still need to know the sock error you mentioned if you need help.